# Distributed transaction among services in a microservice system, using spring-cloud

Tags: java, spring-boot, transactions, jta, distributed-transactions

---

### The current situation

Got a project using: `spring-boot`, `spring-cloud`, `postgresql`, as a microservice system.

There are 2 services, say **SA** and **SB**, they operate on 2 RDBMS databases respectively, say **DA** and **DB**.

Now, there is an operation contains 2 sub steps:

1. Http client would make a request to service **SA**, to save a record `RA`, into `DA`.
2. Then, **SA** send a request to service **SB**, to save a record `RB`, into `DB`.

As a whole, the 2 sub steps should either both commit, or both rollback.

---

### Analysis

- If move both operations into a single service, then could use Spring's distributed transaction to sovled it with JTA *(based on `2PC` protocol)*.
- But here, the 2 operations are in 2 services, and they communicated via http REST protocol. Maybe could use **mq + compensation** to solve this, but I am not sure is there a better approach.

---

### The questions are

- In this case, does JTA *(based on `2PC` protocol)* still work?
- If not, what is the preferred solution?
  Possible solutions I can guess:

  1. Refactor code to move the 2 operations into a single service.
  2. Implementat the **mq + compensation** architecture to support this.

Comment: just curious, what are the challenges do you see with going ahead with 2PC Protocol, I haven't done it myself but I read the spring boot support two-phase commit. https://www.baeldung.com/transactions-across-microservices & https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-jta.html

Comment: @Shailesh `2PC` is `guaranteed` on distributed-transaction, with the cost of performance, the challenage is performance, if there are n sub local transactions, then the slowest one decide the overrall time of the global transaction. IMO, `2PC` is easier to impl with tools provided by Java and Spring, compared to the solution of `mq and compensation `.

Comment: agree with you, If the frequency of operation is low I would suggest going with 2PC, apart from 2PC being easier, it would be easy to maintain/understand by other developers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this project is helpful for you https://github.com/apache/servicecomb-pack

Apache ServiceComb Pack is an eventually data consistency solution for micro-service applications. ServiceComb Pack currently provides TCC and Saga distributed transaction co-ordination solutions by using Alpha as a transaction coordinator and Omega as an transaction agent